# How do I change the default quick form for the CustomerId field in Dynamics CRM 2013?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2013

The CustomerId field that comprises both the Account and Contact records defaults to the Contact Quick Form when creating new records from a Lookup field of that type.

How can I get the field to instead default to the Account Quick Form?

Answer (score 2):

I encountered the same request from a client recently and after some unsuccessful searches we decided that we replace the field on the Form with Account field. Even though there is a Customer filed, there are 2 seperate fields to store Account and Contact by default in CRM.

Therefore we just removed/hid the customer field on the form and added the Account field. Once you populate the Account field, the customer field gets automatically populated.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I've done to set up the Customer lookup to show only **Contact** records.

```
function Form_OnLoad()
...
preFilterLookup();
..
}


function preFilterLookup() {
Xrm.Page.getControl("customerid").addPreSearch(addLookupFilter);
}

function addLookupFilter() {

document.getElementById("customerid_i").setAttribute("lookuptypenames", "contact:2:Contact");
document.getElementById("customerid_i").setAttribute("lookuptypes", "2");
}
```

In case you want to add a filter to the records:

```
function addLookupFilter() {

document.getElementById("customerid_i").setAttribute("lookuptypenames", "contact:2:Contact");
document.getElementById("customerid_i").setAttribute("lookuptypes", "2");

var account = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("aux_account").getValue();

if (account != null) {

    var filter = "<filter type='and'>" + "<condition attribute='parentcustomerid' operator='eq' value='" + account[0].id + "' /></filter>";
    Xrm.Page.getControl("customerid").addCustomFilter(filter);
}
```

}

So, the changes I've done to migrate from CRM 2011 to 2013  are:

Add **_i** when you get the element by: `document.getElementById("customerid_i")`

Use new methods: `addPreSearch` and `addCustomFilter`

You can check these in msdn documentation and easily change code to show only Accounts.