# Default the "Look for" field in a lookup view

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013

If the "look for" drop down contains more than one item (e.g. Account, Contact) is it possible to set the default option (in my scenario to the second option Contact)?

Comment: https://bingsoft.wordpress.com/2011/01/13/default-customer-lookup-to-contact-in-crm-2011/

Comment: Searching for "is it possible to set the default option CRM lookup" yields many results, including the one added in the above comment. Please try to show you have done some research before asking a question.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I was searching using the wrong terms I think.

Comment: Do you want to change the default, or prevent users from selecting Accounts? In the latter case, you could manually edit the solution XML.

Answer (score 0):

In CRM 2015 you can use the following if you want to filter the lookup so it contains only contacts

```
// Filter the dropdown of the lookup so that it only contains contacts + do not allow accounts ,in the contact views, visible when the user clicks more records
    var noAccountsfilter = "<filter type='and'><condition attribute='statecode' operator='ne' value='0' /></filter>";
    Xrm.Page.getControl("parentcustomerid").addCustomFilter(noAccountsfilter, 'account');
```

Answer (score -2):

```
function Form_OnLoad()
...
preFilterLookup();
..
}


 function preFilterLookup() {
 Xrm.Page.getControl("customerid").addPreSearch(addLookupFilter);
 } 

 function addLookupFilter() {

 document.getElementById("customerid_i").setAttribute        ("lookuptypenames", "contact:2:Contact");
 document.getElementById("customerid_i").setAttribute("lookuptypes", "2");
 }
```

[How do I change the default quick form for the CustomerId field in Dynamics CRM 2013?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24856169/how-do-i-change-the-default-quick-form-for-the-customerid-field-in-dynamics-crm)

Comment: That code would not work for CRM 2015 SP1/2016. Good luck with upgrade.

Comment: If it is really neccesary to handle this you should have an OnChange js that ask for the record type, if it doesn't match clean the value from the lookup.

Comment: @AndriiButenko to be fair, the question is tagged as 2013, so this answer should work in this environment.  It's just not good practice to use unsupported code that has been deprecated in future releases

Comment: It's a good thing to at least say that this is not the way that you are "supposed" to code and it might not work after any updates from MS.